# Client libraries in Spring Boot microservices

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, clean-architecture, client-library

Three years ago I was participating as a developer on my first microservices project. I didn't know anything about microservices conceptions. That project was building as Spring Boot microservices. In general nothing special but all projects applied quite controversial way of integration between microservices based on client libraries. I think those client libraries were made by naive way. I'll try to give their main idea.

There are three modules in project: `*-api`, `*-client` and `*-impl`. The `*-impl` is a full-fledged REST-service and `*-client` is a client library for this REST-service. `*-impl` and `*-client` modules depend on the `*-api` (they import `*-api` as a maven dependency). The `*-api` in turn contains Java interfaces which should be implemented by [@RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) classes from the `*-impl` module and by classes which implement functionality of client library for this REST-service (via [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) or [FeignClient](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/)). Also the `*-api` usually contains DTOs which may be covered by [Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/) and [Swagger](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/) annotations. In some cases those interfaces may contain [@RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) annotations from Spring-MVC. Thus implementation of [@RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) and a [FeignClient](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/) at the same time inherit that [@RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html).

***-api**

```
@ApiModel
class DTO {
  @NotNull
  private String field;
  // getters & setters
}

interface Api {
  @RequestMapping("/api")
  void method(DTO dto)
}
```

***-client**

```
@FeignClient("api")
interface Client extends Api {
  // void method(DTO) is inherited and implemented at runtime by Spring Cloud Feign
}
```

***-impl**

```
@RestController
class ApiImpl implements Api {
  void method(@Validated DTO dto) {
    // implementation
  }
}
```

Not hard to guess if some other microservice will pull `*-client` dependency it may get unpredictable transitive dependencies in their classpath. Also appears tightly coupling between microservices.

I decide to dedicate some time for researching this issue and discovered some concepts. First of all I got acquainted with widespread opinions like [this one](https://youtu.be/CZ3wIuvmHeM?t=1157) or from Sam Newman's famous [Building Microservices book](https://samnewman.io/books/building_microservices/) (chapter "Client Libraries"). Also I got knew about [Consumer Driven Contracts](https://martinfowler.com/articles/consumerDrivenContracts.html) and their implementations - [Pact](https://docs.pact.io/) and [Spring Cloud Contract](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract). I decided if I will start a new project with Spring Boot microservices I'll try not to make client libraries and couple microservices by `Consumer Driven Contracts` only. Thus I hope to reach minimum of coupling.

After that project I was participating in the other one and it was building nearly by the same way as the first one regarding client libraries. I tried to share my researching with a team but I didn't get any feedback and all the team continued to make client libraries. After several months I left project.

Recently I became a developer on my third microservices project where Spring Boot is used too. And I faced that there also used the same way with client libraries as on prevous two projects. There I also couldn't get any feedback about `Consumer Driven Contracts` using.

**I would like to know an opinion of community. Which way do you use on your projects? Is the above mentioned way with client libraries reasonable?**

### Appendix 1.

@JRichardsz's questions:

> 1. What do you mean by client? client of rest api is a kind of sdk provided by api owner to allow clients to consume it in an easy way
>    instead http low level implementations.
> 2. what do you mean with integrations? is test integrations what you need?
> 3. I think your requirement is related to how organize source code between several apis. Is it correct?

Answers:

1. Here I consider only Spring/Spring Cloud. If I build a microservice with Spring Boot and I want to interact/integrate (this is what I mean by "integrations") with another (micro)service I can use [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) (it's a kind of a client library, isn't it?). If I would build a microservice with Spring Boot + Spring Cloud I could use
   [Spring Cloud OpenFeign](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/) for interactions (or integration) with another (micro)service. I think [Spring Cloud OpenFeign](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/) is also a kind of a client library, isn't it?
   In my general question I talk about custom client libraries which were created by teams where I worked. For example there are two projects: microserviceA and microserviceB. Each of these projects contain three maven modules: `*-api`, `*-client` and `*-impl`. It's implied that `*-client` maven module includes `*-api` maven module. Also `*-api` maven module used as a dependency in the `*-impl` maven module. When the microserviceA (`microserviceA-impl` maven module) wants to interact with the microserviceB it will import the `microserviceB-client` maven module. Thus microserviceA and microserviceB are tightly coupled.
2. By integrations I mean interactions between microservices. For example, microserviceA interacts/integrates with microserviceB.
3. My point concludes in opinion that microserviceA and microserviceB must not to have common source code (via client library). And that's why I ask these questions:

> Which way do you use on your projects? Is the above mentioned way with
> client libraries reasonable?

### Appendix 2.

I'll try to explain in details and with examples.

#### Introduction.

When I participated in projects which were built as microservices they used the same way to implement interactions between microservices namely "client libraries". They are not the client libraries which incapsulate low level http interactions, serializing/deserializing of http body (and so on) as `RestTemplate` or `FeighClient`. They are custom client libraries which have the only purpose - to make interactions (request/response) with the only microservice. For example, there is some `microservice-b` which offers some `microservice-b-client.jar` (it's a custom client library) and `microservice-a` should use this `jar` for interact with `microservice-b`. It's very similar to [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) implementation.

#### Example.

***microservice-b project***

***microservice-b-api maven module***

pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>microservice-b-api</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

HelloController interface:

```
@Api("Hello API")
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public interface HelloController {
    @PostMapping
    HelloResponse hello(@RequestBody HelloRequest request);
}
```

*HelloRequest dto:*

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ApiModel("request model")
public class HelloRequest {
    @NotNull
    @ApiModelProperty("name property")
    private String name;
}
```

HelloResponse dto:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ApiModel("response model")
public class HelloResponse {
    @ApiModelProperty("greeting property")
    private String greeting;
}
```

***microservice-b-client maven module***

pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>microservice-b-client</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.rinat</groupId>
        <artifactId>microservice-b-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

HelloClient interface:

```
@FeignClient(value = "hello", url = "http://localhost:8181")
public interface HelloClient extends HelloController {
}
```

***microservice-b-impl maven module***

pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>microservice-b-impl</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.rinat</groupId>
        <artifactId>microservice-b-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

MicroserviceB class:

```
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
public class MicroserviceB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceB.class, args);
    }
}
```

HelloControllerImpl class:

```
@RestController
public class HelloControllerImpl implements HelloController {
    @Override
    public HelloResponse hello(HelloRequest request) {
        var hello = new HelloResponse();
        hello.setGreeting("Hello " + request.getName());
        return hello;
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8181
```

***microservice-a project***

pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>microservice-a</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.rinat</groupId>
        <artifactId>microservice-b-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

MicroserviceA class:

```
@Slf4j
@EnableFeignClients(basePackageClasses = HelloClient.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class MicroserviceA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceA.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner hello(HelloClient client) {
        return args -> {
            var request = new HelloRequest();
            request.setName("StackOverflow");
            var response = client.hello(request);
            log.info(response.getGreeting());
        };
    }
}
```

Result of MicroserviceA run:

```
2020-01-02 10:06:20.623  INFO 22288 --- [           main] com.example.microservicea.MicroserviceA  : Hello StackOverflow
```

[Here you can see full example](https://github.com/MarkHuntDev/my-spring-framework-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-microservices-with-client-libraries)

#### Question.

I think this way of integration between microservices (via custom client libraries) is a wrong way. **First of all microservices become tightly-coupled. Second - client library brings undesirable dependencies.** Despite these circumstances the teams where I worked used that odd way to make integration between microservices. **I would like to know is this way to make integration of microservices reasonable (correct)? Which is the best practice to make integrations between microservices?**

**P.S. In my opinion Spring Boot microservices should be coupled by [Consumer Driven Contracts](https://martinfowler.com/articles/consumerDrivenContracts.html) ([Spring Cloud Contract](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract) or [Pact](https://docs.pact.io/)) and nothing else. How do you think is it right way?**

Comment: You might want to look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033686/pact-vs-spring-cloud-contract-tests

Comment: is your question related to how modularize spring boot code (several apis) using libraries (service, dto, etc) or contract test as @OlgaMaciaszek said?

Comment: @JRichardsz it's rather about how to organize client libraries in spring-boot microservices. Do we really need to use them? I think the example that I mentioned in my question is really brings tightly-coupling to microservices but most of the projects do use them anyway. Why? What is the best practice to create integrations between microservices?

Comment: #1 What do you mean by **client**? client of rest api is a kind of sdk provided by api owner to allow clients to consume it in an easy way instead http low level implementations.  #2 what do you mean with **integrations**? is test integrations what you need? #3 I think your requirement is related to how organize source code between several apis. Is it correct?

Comment: @JRichardsz I've answered your questions in "Appendix 1" section. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why don't you use interface driven controllers of Spring 5.1. That way the `-api` module will have all `@RequestMapping`. Both `-impl` and `-client` will add only `-api` as dependency. `-impl` will have `@RestController` and `-client` will have `@FeignClient`

Comment: @SaptarshiBasu see "Appendix 2" please

Answer (score 4):

Here an strategy to build dozens of apis and test them. This works and I used it in my jobs.

Assuming that I work for acme.org and I need to develop two apis: employee-api and customer-api. You could use **-microservice** instead **-api** suffix.

## Parents and Libraries

If I will develop several apis and apps with my team, we need to re-use code across our developments, so the first task before start the development is **create our common libraries and relationships between them**.

For this task I will recommend you:

- use maven parents
- constantly review the java code of world class libraries like : spring, mule esb, pentaho, apache, google/amazon sdks, etc. They have good ways to name their classes, libraries and relations ships. For example  this strategy: starters of spring boot

Here some of my libraries which are maven projects (maven parents(.pom) and just libraries(.jar) :

- acme-base

  - parent project with the java version `<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>` for all applications and other general properties like `project.build.sourceEncoding`, etc
  - any java project in acme.org must use this parent. It would be a pain manage several apis with several java versions :s
- acme-base-spring

  - parent project with the main spring classes and versions : spring-web, spring-core, spring-context
  - not all developments in acme.org will be an api rest. Could be libraries, schedules or demos, etc. So if they need some spring libraries, they must use this parent
- acme-base-spring-boot-api

  - parent project with general spring boot configurations and starters.
  - spring boot, reduced all but if you will have several apps, we can reduce them even more.
  - this project must **spring-boot-starter-parent** as parent and **acme-base-spring** as super pom.
  - this project has this build configs and dependencies spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-starter-actuator, spring-boot-starter-test, spring-boot-devtools, spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-tomcat
- acme-base-api

  - this parent project must use **acme-base-spring-boot-api** as parent.

With these parents, your **employee-api** could have a minimal pom like:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.acme.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>employees-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.acme.base</groupId>
        <artifactId>acme-base-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

</project>
```

- employee-model

  - this project is not a parent. Is just a library (.jar)
  - goal of this project is store all the entities in acme.org
  - must use **acme-base** as parent.
  - if you will use jpa anotattions, add jpa libraries here.
- employee-persistent

  - java library which use **employee-model** as dependency.
  - could store the daos or jpa repositoties

With these parents and dependencies, your **employee-api** could have a minimal pom like:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.acme.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>employees-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.acme.base</groupId>
        <artifactId>acme-base-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.acme.api.employee</groupId>
            <artifactId>employee-model</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.acme.api.employee</groupId>
            <artifactId>employee-persistent</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>  

</project>
```

Then customer-api and employee-api have code which works in both of them, so a new library is required

- acme-common

  - this project must be used as **dependency** in customer-api, employee-api and any other api in acme.org

Here a list of some common libraries across multiple rest apis:

- acme-api-log

  - usage of logger and [mdc](https://www.sipios.com/blog-tech/how-to-use-logj-and-mdc-in-java-spring-boot-application) to add metadata in each log entry
  - externalize logs with [google stack driver](https://github.com/jrichardsz/spring-boot-templates/tree/master/009-logback-with-stackdriver-mdc), [gray log](https://www.graylog.org), etc
- acme-api-audit

  - add [unique identifier](https://medium.com/@d.lopez.j/spring-boot-setting-a-unique-id-per-request-dd648efef2b) in each request for an easy traceability or error support.
- acme-api-errors

  - exceptions, [controller advice](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/408092af5daf416b3dea87a04509e3f6), exceptions handlers, etc
- acme-api-health

  - endpoins like /health /status which must be published for any api.

---

## Test with Spring Cloud Contract

Nowadays, applications are thoroughly tested - whether it be unit tests, integration tests, or end-to-end tests. It's very common in a microservice architecture that a service (consumer) communicates with another service (producer) to complete a request.

To test them, we have two options:

- #1 Deploy all microservices and perform end-to-end tests using a library like Selenium : **require more infrastructure**
- #2 Write integration tests by mocking the calls to other services : **the mocks won't reflect changes in the production api**

In #2 approach , our integration test cases will still work just fine, because others apis were **mocked** The issue will likely be noticed in a staging or production environment, instead of the elaborate test cases.

**Spring Cloud Contract** provides us with the Spring Cloud Contract Verifier exactly for these cases. It creates a stub (.jar) from the producer (api) which can be used by the consumer service to **mock** the calls.

So, instead of making our **local mocks**, we can download the stubs from the producer (api) to **create more real mocks**

> Recommended reading : https://stackabuse.com/spring-cloud-contract/

---

## sdk or rest-client

As previous point said:  It's very common in a microservice architecture that a service (consumer) communicates with another service (producer) to complete a request.

This is commonly implemented with [RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template).

I have another strategy: Develop a kind of sdk provided by any api rest. This sdk contains the low level or complex http invocation with RestTemplate: http methods, json binding, errors, etc

Example: If employee-api needs to consume some endpoint (/verify-existence) of customer-api we need:

- customer-api-sdk or customer-api-rest-client. This library has the required source code to consume customer-api.
- employee-api add **customer-api-sdk** as dependency. Instead of http low level implementation to consume customer-api, will only need:

```java
CustomerApiPassport passport = new CustomerApiPassport();
passport.setBaseUrl("http://customer-api.com");
passport.etc();

CustomerApiSecurity security = new CustomerApiSecurity();
security.setToken("");
security.setBasicAuthentication("user", "password");
security.etc();

CustomerApiSdk customerSdk = new CustomerApiSdk();
customerSdk.setPassport(passport);
customerSdk.setSecurity(security);

VerifyCustomerExistenceRequest request = new VerifyCustomerExistenceRequest();
request.setCustomerPersonId("215456");

//consume /verify-existence endpoint
VerifyCustomerExistenceResponse response = customerSdk.verifyCustomerExistence(request);
response.exist();
```

- **customer-api-sdk** is not only for employee-api. Could be used for any api which require consume some endpoint in **customer-api**
- This **customer-api-sdk** could be used for mocks like jars generated for **Spring Cloud Contract**
- The idea of sdk and passport were taken from : google and amazon sdks (perform http request to its platforms), soap client generated for axis, jaxws, etc

Comment: Great example, thank you! Your approach with the parent project has give me a big clarification. If it would be possible about negotiating with a team about this approach it could be resolve many issues about client libraries, shared libraries, API versions and so on.

Comment: But how @Filippo Possenti already mentioned this question has many trade-offs that's why I haven't yet accept the answer as a solution.

Comment: That's a very structured example. I am doing something very similar in my current company and previous companies were also trying to structure their modules in similar ways. The key is always whether it solves a problem you have or one you don't have yet (and may never have). As said I am also using it and it does solve some problems... but make sure you do have those problems before you try and solve them. Aside from that, it's a good structure that I would generally recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:
I don't think there is a single definitive answer to your questions. More specifically, I believe that the best solution changes over time based on the evolution of a project so the following can be considered in large part "personal opinions". My hope is that people will express their opinion like I did rather than expressing a vote on my answer, whether it's an upward or downward vote.

---

One of the purposes of microservices is indeed to "simplify" integration and evolution of a software product, which does in fact raise questions as to the benefit of locking the client to a common API library.

As there are even stories of companies migrating back from microservices to monoliths however, I would never dare stating that an approach is definitely wrong or definitely right.

In some cases it may not be such a bad idea to use client libraries as the additional burden can force undisciplined developers into coordinating and guaranteeing that an updated client will always be developed alongside with the actual service. Still, it wouldn't be my first choice unless I have specific needs, probably tied more to the variance in the level of skills and methodologies used by different development teams within a company.

I personally believe that the simplest possible approach (`customer contracts`) works well for applications with a small number of clients/customers (another microservice IS a client/customer) and allows to be immediately productive, which helps reducing the time to market/release while supporting the startup phase of a company.

As the company grows, the need for more structure kicks in and choices need to be reviewed due to the increased maintenance costs and frustration related to `customer contracts`, at which point the available information about the business and related needs greatly helps selecting the "next" way to go, which is probably `customer-driven contracts` by virtue of them being closed and complete, which is desirable for a number of reasons and also something you can achieve only after you learned what matters to your customers.

Painful experiences may lead to the choice of relying on client libraries but I believe that's uncommon and more likely to happen on "brand new" projects by virtue of the technical lead being left with "unprocessed trauma" from a previous project that overstayed the `customer contracts` pattern where it should have migrated to `customer-driven contracts` instead.

The key to me is making one critical choice at the beginning to make room for the possibility to almost completely change idea in the future, thus allowing to support future growth without having to "pull the plug" on older clients immediately as business continuity just doesn't allow for such a move. One way to do it is to give the API a codename included in the URL, thus allowing future versions to be neatly separated allowing a grace period for consumers to upgrade. The codename is, effectively, the name of the product your company is selling.

---

To explicitly try and answer your questions:

***Which way do you use on your projects?*** It really depends on who's going to use my microservice. If it's a specific actor within my company and also using Java, I prefer to provide a full-blown client (with related sourcecode) when I'm exposing a microservice to them and ask that they do the same when they are exposing a microservice to me. This allows to avoid at least some of the problems like them blaming me because "it doesn't work" with the problem being instead in their client as well as preventing misunderstandings on the inner workings of a given microservice and pushing actors to develop microservices that are reasonably stable (that is: people will refrain from constantly changing the "signatures" in order to avoid having to rebuild the corresponding client... basically, I exploit our innate laziness). They are clearly not required to use my client and I am not required to use theirs either: it's more of a "statement" that the microservice works, meant to allow each party to figure out where the real problem is by inspecting each other's client code. This also allows to see how they code, which gives an insight on the quality that can be expected from the microservice's code and, thus, how robust and predictable is hopefully going to be.

***Is the above mentioned way with client libraries reasonable? Is this way to make integration of microservices reasonable (correct)?*** Sometimes it is, sometimes it's not. I wouldn't use client libraries to be honest but for simple architectures it could work and could ensure that everybody is on the same page so it's not necessarily a bad thing.

***Which is the best practice to make integrations between microservices?*** I believe it changes over time, based on the project. I would start letting consumers fend for themselves in favour of a quicker time-to-market, well aware that I will be necessarily starting with `consumer contracts` (even though I will try to future-proof the architecture to some extent) and let experience and growth solidify the architecture into a `consumer-driven contracts` one.

***How do you think is it right way?*** The right way is the one that allows you to get a product to the market well before competitors but not so much that will hamper future growth. That's not much of an answer to be honest, but truth is your question is very difficult to answer and highly depending on the scope of a project. The point being that the right way will most likely change over time so you should aim at choosing a solution that you believe will allow growth for 3-5 years while at the same time providing a contingency that will allow you to gracefully migrate to one that will support growth for the subsequent 8-10 years. This also means that "the right way" is not just a technical matter but also a management approach to the business, specifically one that allows methodical planning for the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not against client libraries if they have clean architecture but my example has critical disadvantages (unruled tightly-coupling, undesirable dependencies) and I wouldn't like to apply this approach in my project. I would like to see "clean" examples that could be applied in real projects.

Comment: The example provided in the other answer is what a company with a consolidated set of APIs eventually goes towards. So that constitutes your most structured example. At the very beginnings, on the other hand, your example looks more like those you can find in tutorials. It might seem "unprofessional" but there's beauty in simplicity and it allows you to focus on the features.